# networkx draw_network draws a frame around the plot. How can I prevent this?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I do some manipulations on graphs/networks and want to plot the results and save them to a pdf (actually the format does not really matter, but I think pdf is fine).

I give you a minimal example:

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

g=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(20,.2,directed=True)
nx.draw_networkx(g)
#plt.show()
plt.savefig('so_example.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The result is OK, except that there is a thick black frame around the picture:

[image: graph with thick frame]

Does anybody know a way to prevent this frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `plt.box(False)`. See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

g=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(20,.2,directed=True)
nx.draw_networkx(g)
plt.box(False)
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]